# Перемещение объекта по экрану

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер.
Решил написать небольшую игру на JavaScript. Опыта разработки игр у меня не было, но сам JS знаю на достаточном уровне.
Игру, для начала, напишу на HTML + JavaScript. Начал разработку, все идет по плану, но хочу кое-что уточнить. Дело в том, что есть небольшой объект — HTML-тэг, который нужно будет перемещать по экрану нажатием кнопок на клавиатуре. Использую событие *onkeypress*, но не уверен, что это лучший вариант. Трабла в том, что когда документ не сфокусирован, *onkeypress* не работает. И еще: перемещение (скажем, человечка) по экрану будет выполняться несколькими кнопками (W,A,S,D — вверх, влево, вниз, вправо), а мне пока-что удалось задействовать только одно перемещение. То есть комбинация W+D (вверх и вправо) у меня не получается. Как сию фишку реализовать? Я же просто-напросто делал так:

```
document.onkeypress = function(key){
 var keycode = (key.which)?key.which:key.keyCode;
 if (keycode == "...") // перемещение на 10 пикселей в нужную сторону... 
 ...
};
```

Comment: как только кнопка нажата вешаем интервал на передвижение в том или ином направлении, как только кнопка отпущена - убираем интервал... Таким образом будет возможно передвижение по диагонали<br>
<small>Писать обработчики на все возможные сочитания клавиш передвижения ИМХО глупо</small>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Field.prototype.setUserDir = function(key){
    if(key == 65){
        if(this.user.dirXstates.length < 2 && this.user.dirXstates[0] != -1)
            this.user.dirXstates[this.user.dirXstates.length] = -1;
    }
    else if(key == 68){
        if(this.user.dirXstates.length < 2 && this.user.dirXstates[0] != 1)
            this.user.dirXstates[this.user.dirXstates.length] = 1;
    }
    else if(key == 83){
        if(this.user.dirYstates.length < 2 && this.user.dirYstates[0] != 1)
            this.user.dirYstates[this.user.dirYstates.length] = 1;
    }
    else if(key == 87){
        if(this.user.dirYstates.length < 2 && this.user.dirYstates[0] != -1)
            this.user.dirYstates[this.user.dirYstates.length] = -1;
    }
};

Field.prototype.unsetUserDir = function(key){
    if(key == 65){
        if(this.user.dirXstates[0] == -1)
            this.user.dirXstates.splice(0,1);
        else if(this.user.dirXstates[1] == -1)
            this.user.dirXstates.splice(1,1);
    }
    else if(key == 68){
        if(this.user.dirXstates[0] == 1)
            this.user.dirXstates.splice(0,1);
        else if(this.user.dirXstates[1] == 1)
            this.user.dirXstates.splice(1,1);
    }
    else if(key == 83){
        if(this.user.dirYstates[0] == 1)
            this.user.dirYstates.splice(0,1);
        else if(this.user.dirYstates[1] == 1)
            this.user.dirYstates.splice(1,1);
    }
    else if(key == 87){
        if(this.user.dirYstates[0] == -1)
            this.user.dirYstates.splice(0,1);
        else if(this.user.dirYstates[1] == -1)
            this.user.dirYstates.splice(1,1);
    }
};

...

User.prototype.move = function(){
    if(!this.dirXstates.length && !this.dirYstates.length) return;
    else if(this.dirXstates.length && this.dirYstates.length) var k = 0.7;
    else var k = 1;

    this.x += Math.round((this.dirXstates[this.dirXstates.length-1] || 0) * k * this.speed);
    this.y += Math.round((this.dirYstates[this.dirYstates.length-1] || 0) * k * this.speed);
};
```

Немного наговнокожено, но смысл прослеживается. У объекта игрока есть два стека флагов. Первый - для смещения по Х, второй - по У. При нажатии на клавишу в соответствующий стек записывается направление смещения объекта (при отпускании - удаляется), а при отрисовке следующего кадра объект смещается в зависимости от последнего значения. В каждый стек умещается по два значения, чтобы можно было быстрее "переключатся" между направлениями - не надо отпускать клавишу, чтобы обнулить направление до задания нового.

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё легко сделать с jquery. Скачать этот js файл можно с сайта jquery.com
Вот примерно как реализуется.

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Пример</title>
        </head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('body').keydown(function(event)
                {
                   if (event.keyCode == 37)
                        alert("Нажато <-");
                   if (event.keyCode == 38)
                        alert("Нажато ^");    
                    if (event.keyCode == 39)
                        alert("Нажато ->");
                    if (event.keyCode == 40)
                        alert("Нажато v");
                });
            }); 
        </script>
    </html>
```